# Why is that the JavaScript fetch Response's body considered already used?

Tags: javascript, fetch-api, service-worker

I am a beginner at JavaScript and am currently trying to write a service worker for a PWA.

Here is the way I am intercepting fetch requests (cache-first strategy) :

```
async function cache(request, response)
{
    if (response.type !== "error" && response.type !== "opaque") 
    {//don't cache network errors
        try 
        {
            const currentCache = await caches.open(CACHE_NAME);
            currentCache.put(request, response.clone());
        }
        catch(e)
        {
            console.error(e);
        }
    }
}

async function fetch_response(req)
{
    try 
    {
        let response = await caches.match(req);
        if (!response)
        {//response is not in cache, fetching
            response = await fetch(req);
            cache(req, response);
        }
        return response;
    }
    catch (e)
    {
        console.error(e);
    }
}

function when_fetch(event)
{
    const response = fetch_response(req)
    event.respondWith(response);
}

self.addEventListener("fetch", when_fetch);
```

My problem is that the line:

```
currentCache.put(request, response.clone());
```

raises the following error:

> TypeError: Failed to execute 'clone' on 'Response': Response body is already used

I don't understand why this is so: I am not using the response body before as I am calling function `cache` immediately after fetching (and removing the check for response.type doesn't change anything).

Comment: Hard to say exactly why, but the reasons for errors occurring during cloning are given in [the spec](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#ref-for-dom-response-clone%E2%91%A0)... It could be the response has a status of 204 No Content, and therefore has no body to clone.

Comment: Are you calling `response.json()` somewhere in code you're not showing us before you call `response.clone()` ?

Comment: I am not using the response object anywhere else.

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are encountering a race condition. You have missed a few `await`s.

You should do

```
const response = await fetch_response(req)
```

and

```
await cache(req, response);
```

Without the `await`, you will have already consumed the response before it could be consumed.

Hope this fixes your issue.

Comment: That almost did the trick, now I'm getting : DOMException: Failed to execute 'respondWith' on 'FetchEvent': The event handler is already finished. On the line "event.respondWith(response);"

Comment: OK, it worked if I only apply the second line you suggest : await cache(req, response), if I also use the first one, this causes the DOMException. Would you know why? Shouldn't your first await pause the exection?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar use case, and I've developed a library called CacheFirst, which you can find at https://github.com/lakshminathan/CacheFirst. This library is designed to store fetch response in localS. Give it a try, and feel free to let me know if it proves helpful.